# How do you get the signing key used for HS512 from Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

I am attempting to get the symmetric key used to sign my bearer tokens using HS512 on Keycloak 7.0. When I set my default signing algorithm to HS512 under realm settings -> tokens, my token is signed with the new algorithm as expected, but I have no way to validate this token.

I am able to access a public key/cert pair for the default RS256 algorithm  under realm settings -> keys as well as through http://localhost:9000/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/certs. HS512 shows up under realm settings -> keys with no values for public keys, and it does not show up at all under http://localhost:9000/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/certs.

How can I gain access to the key used to verify my signature? I would think this is something that would be relatively trivial as it is a core functionality to authorization but there is seemingly no way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my secret key by doing a command line export of the keycloak server
using:

```
/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/standalone.sh -Dkeycloak.migration.action=export -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak-export -Dkeycloak.migration.usersExportStrategy=DIFFERENT_FILES -Dkeycloak.migration.usersPerFile=100 -Djboss.http.port=8888 -Djboss.https.port=9999 -Djboss.management.http.port=7777 -Djboss.management.https.port=7776
```

and searching the files created. I did not find the secret in the export files generated by exporting through the UI - but it may also be possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DB for `Keycloak` storage, than secret is available by this query:

```sql
SELECT
    R.name AS realm_name,
    CC.value AS secret
FROM component_config CC
    JOIN component C ON (CC.component_id = C.id)
    JOIN realm R ON (R.id = C.realm_id)
WHERE
    provider_id = 'hmac-generated'
    AND CC.name = 'secret';
```

Keycloak v20.0.3